# Best way for progress & activity bars on Android: GIF or code?

Tags: user-interface, animation, android-activity, progress

I'm an 2D animator and am new to Android development. I have one idea about creating animated stocks for Android, but what's the best way to create a progress and activity bar, GIF or code?

Using GIF images you have no limits. A lot of animation and effects
using are code, and you have custom control of everything.

So, what's the best? Is it a good idea to use GIF images?